# MVP / MVC role of the Model (not anemic one) clashes with presenter / controller role (responsibilities in the right place, Model OR Presenter)?

Tags: mvc, domain-model, model, mvp

## Problem?

I have been looking at MVP implementation and process to design a good domain model (**not anemic**). It says that the domain model should have its own behavior and not being a simple data model (like DTO).

In my case (my application), it turns out that controllers architecture is following the model architecture (player model, player controller, game model, game controller, ...). So I think my model is anemic because my model objects does not contains references to other models objets, they define a lot of accessors methods (get & set) and finally their core methods only modify their own object properties.

*How do I integrate a Model handling business logic into MVP architecture? And who should manage which kind of action? Does the presenter architecture have to follow the model architecture? Should a presenter only have access to a part of the model or all of them? Does the presenter have to listen to model modification and react accordingly? Any concret resource on the net with examples?*

## Solution?

Create a structured Model with inheritance and behavior. Link related model objects (like collections, property of another model object, ...). Finally listen to model events modification into controllers for sending requests onto network.

But, in that case, the role of the controller is very small, because the model handle almost every modification itself. Isn't it better to "flatten" the model hierarchy, so they are not dependency between each others ?

I am confused.

---

## Here is an example of my current app architecture

In the following cases, I think the model is anemic.

Context: In multiplayer game application over network. Let's say we have two players with a certain amount of balls that they have to throw into a barrel (players have their own barrel each). Its a turn based game.

So the domain model would be (properties are not typed):

- Game (playerTurn)
- Player (name, score, number of balls thrown)
- Ball (color, weight)
- Barrel (distance, points, list of balls thrown into)

In the MVP representation, I would create three Presenters:

- GameController
- PlayerController
- BarrelController

### Example of use

#### Use case n°1: The player (real one) throws a ball

[image: call flow - use case number one]

In resume, player throws a ball. Event is dispatched to GameController which validate action over network and responds back by delegating event to each specific controller.

*code for generating (and modify) diagramm ()*

```
View -> PlayerController : onThrowBall() 
PlayerController -> GameController : onPlayerThrowsBall() 
GameController -> GameModel : isTurn() 
GameModel --> GameController : true 
GameController -> Network : onPlayerThrowsBall() 
Network --> GameController : true
GameController -> GameModel : updateTurn(player) 
GameController -> PlayerController : throwBall() 
PlayerController -> PlayerModel : updateBallThrownCount() 
PlayerController -> View : update()
```

#### Use case n°2: The thrown ball fall into the barrel

[image]

Same principe, action is dispatched for validation (and perform potential related action into parent controllers). Finally, barrel is updated by BarrelController (add ball) and player model is updated by PlayerController (update score).

*code for generating (and modify) diagramm ()*

```
View -> BarrelController : onBallFallIntoBarrel()
BarrelController -> PlayerController : onBallFallIntoBarrel()
PlayerController -> GameController : onBallFallIntoBarrel()
GameController -> GameModel : isTurn()
GameModel --> GameController : true
GameController -> Network : onPlayerThrowsBallIntoBarrel()
Network --> GameController : true
GameController -> GameModel : updateTurn()
GameController -> PlayerController : throwBallIntoBarrel()
PlayerController -> BarrelController : throwBallIntoBarrel()
BarrelController -> BarrelModel : addBall()
PlayerController -> PlayerModel : updateScore()
PlayerController -> View : update()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Domain Driven Design](http://dddcommunity.org).

> Domain-driven design (DDD) is an approach to developing software for complex needs by deeply connecting the implementation to an evolving model of the core business concepts.

This is the opposite of Anemic Domain Model.

Check out [Crafting Wicked Domain Models](https://vimeo.com/43598193) for a more hands on example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Greg Burghardt. I have checked these links already. My question is not really related to how design a good model (not anemic one). But, how this kind of model (not anemic) works in MVP / MVC architecture (putting responsibilities in the right place, Model OR Presenter) in uses cases like online multiplayer game as an exemple which requires sending each action to the network. I have edited my previous post for asking the correct questions.